# Structure nav tag changing depth when on page of parent

Tags: structure

This is confusing and not sure why it is happening. I do not commonly use Structure, so apologize in advance if this is a duh!

I have this tag:

`{exp:structure:nav add_level_classes='yes' show_depth='2' start_from="shareholders"}`

When on any page of the site it shows 2 levels. However when in the actual section that this nav is showing the links to, I get depth of 3. It is almost appears it is pulling them dynamically because if you click on one of those pages you get only that item in the nav.

I didn't see anything in the docs about dynamic navs...

Structure version is: 3.3.8 EE version is: 2.5.5

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried the max_depth="2" parameter? (http://buildwithstructure.com/tags#tag_navigation)

Answer (score 2):

I looks like your missing the `/` in the `start_from` parameter, this could be causing the issue. Also, add the `max_depth` parameter like Mark suggested if you want to cap the depth

```
{exp:structure:nav add_level_classes='yes' show_depth='2' start_from="/shareholders"}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that did not fix it. Same Results.

Comment: That's odd; start_from really ought to fix it even if it's not dynamically setting the parent for some reason. What version of Structure are you using? This sounds like a bug; you might want to get ahold of Jack.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the issue by adding max_depth="2". It appears that structure dynamically ignores the show_depth parameter when inside that section.

Comment: `max_depth` and `show_depth` get me every time, and I've been using Structure for years.

Comment: I always add both parameters to any Structure nav tag I have in my templates because it consistently causes issues like this if you don't.